# AMD wavefront vs. workgroup

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I'm a little confused about terms of an AMD wavefront and workgroupsize of OpenCL.
I found different sources were different statements are done.

My question is: How much is the wavefront-size of AMDs GCN technology and according to this: How big should a workgroup on opencl at least be to not waste occupancy.

The information i got out of [this document](https://www.amd.com/Documents/GCN_Architecture_whitepaper.pdf) of amd is, that the wavefront-size of GCN is 16. I can run 4 wavefronts on CU at a time and there is a maximum of 40 in-flight wavefronts per cu. so what i imply out of this is, that a workgroup should be at least of size 16 in opencl.

But the common information (for example in [this](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236607/Winter2013-2014/ho/WCFiles/GPU%20utilization%20on%20GCN.pdf) or [this](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/opencl-optimization-guide/#50401334_pgfId-521164)) is that wavefrontsize is 64 and according to this workgroupsize should be at least 64 an if higher a multiple of 64. This is also what matches with the meassurements on my kernel, which are that with workgroupsize 64 i get highest performance, for everything below 64 its getting worse.

Thanks very much for clarification.

Comment: if work group size is 16, an amd gpu's minimum hardware simd width is wasted by %75 because each of them is 64 wide. You waste 48 units per CU. Wavefronts are applied to same area, not distributed to all CU.

Comment: yeah thats what i get out of the most sources. but whats about link nr.1 there it says in a cu there are 4 16-wide SIMDs and each of that is able to have 10 wavefronts in flight. for me that means that a wavefront is 16 and not 64.

remember my question is especially about amd's GCN tecnology.

Comment: When you have 16-width work group, you use only one 16-width simd. Other 3 waits idle while all wavefronts issued on that single simd so its not dynamic parallelism I think.

Comment: i think you don't understand exactly what my question is. where do you get the information that wavefront size is 64 and not 16 at GCN?

Comment: http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/07/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide-rev-2.7.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it out wrong. Read [this document](https://www.amd.com/Documents/GCN_Architecture_whitepaper.pdf) carefully once again. SIMD unit has got 16 work items and wavefront size is 64 work items. Here are the important quotes:

page 3:

> In GCN, each CU includes 4 separate SIMD units for vector processing. Each of these SIMD units simultaneously executes a single operation across 16 work
>   items, but each can be working on a separate wavefront.

page 5:

> This is essential for wavefront control flow; for example, comparisons will generate a result for each of the 64 work-items in a wavefront.

Comment: Okay you're right. But then my next question is: How it is possible that each Vector16-SIMD can have 10 Wavefronts in flight, when a wavefront is 64 wide and not 16?

Comment: Each 16-wide SIMD processes one 64-wide wavefront over 4 clock cycles. On each clock cycle the instruction scheduler can issue one vector instruction from one wavefront active on the CU to one of the four SIMD units. So over 4 cycles each SIMD has an instruction issued to it and the scheduler is back to the start. There are 10 waves in flight based on resources - 10 program counter registers per SIMD, 40 per CU. I gave a couple of talks that try to explain aspects of this, maybe they would help: http://www.leehowes.com/files/talks/201203-Howes-UTAustin_Lecture_February2012_AMD.pdf